# Why can't I set my Pentax K-5 IIs to ISO 100?

Tags: iso, camera-settings, pentax

I recently got a K-5 IIs, and found that it can't be adjusted to under ISO 200. 
Even with expanded ISO mode, 160 is the lowest possible value.

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You  apparently have *Highlight Correction* activated. This forces the higher ISO limit (usually forcing it from 100 to 200, though you also have *Expanded Sensitivity* enabled, which gives you a broader ISO range starting at 80, thus now 160).

So, there's nothing wrong with your camera.

Mind you: Options you find that look superior may come with a downside. Nothing's for free, and there are reasons why Pentax hasn't enabled every seemingly powerful option by default. ;)

Comment: Most likely what this means is that the highlight correction uses the sensor gain for one stop lower than the selected ISO, with the same exposure (thus "underexposing"), then pushes the exposure using curves.